# Show compact operators on Hilbert spaces self-adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis

Trying to solve the following exercise.

Let H be a separable Hilbert space and $T\in K(H)$ (hence T is compact)
with infinite spectrum $\sigma(T) = \{0\}\cup\{\lambda_i|i \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Suppose that $V_{\lambda_i}=E_{\lambda_i}$
for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and that for all $x\in H$ we have $lim_{m\to\infty} y_m = 0$ in every
decomposition $x = y_m + z_m$ with respect to the topological direct sum $H = \cap_{i=1}^m F_{\lambda_i} \oplus \bigoplus^m_{i=1} E_{\lambda_i}$ :
Construct a sequence $(e_K)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ of linearly independent eigenvectors of T
for which $< e_k | k\in \mathbb{N} >$ = H.

I think I would be able to construct if I knew that T was a self-adjoint operator but I'm sure how to realize this?

Comment: what is $\cap_{i=1}^{m}F_{\lambda_i}$? The orthogonal complement of $\oplus_{i=1}^{m}E_{\lambda_i}$?

Answer (score 0):

If $H=\cap_{i=1}^{m}F_{\lambda_i}\oplus \bigoplus_{i=1}^{m}E_{\lambda_i}$ means $$\tag{1}H=E_m^\perp \oplus E_m$$ where $E_m=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{m}E_{\lambda_i}$ ( i guess you mean that $F_{\lambda_i}=E_{\lambda_i}^\perp$ ). Then, you can procceed as follows:

Since $T$ is compact every $E_{\lambda_i}$ is finite dimensional. For every $i$ let $(e_{ik})_{1\leq k \leq N_i}$ be an orthonomal basis of $E_{\lambda_i}$. Let $$E=\overline{\text{span}\biggl(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_{\lambda_i}\biggr)}$$
Then, the set $\{e_{ik}:\, i\in \mathbb{N},\ 1\leq k \leq N_1\}$ is an orthonomal basis of $E$ constitutes of eigenvectors of $T$. We claim that $H=E$, this shows also that the kernel of $T$ is trivial. Meaning that $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$. For the proof of our claim write $H=E\oplus E^\perp$. Suppose that $E^\perp\neq \emptyset$. Pick $x\in E^\perp$. Then, from $(1)$ for every $m$ there exists $y_m\in E_m^\perp,\, z_m\in E_m$ such that $x=y_m+z_m$. By our hypothesis,
$$z_m=x-y_m\to x$$
(since $y_m\to 0$). But, $z_m \in E_m\subseteq E$. Since, $E$ is closed, it follows that $x\in E$. But, since $x\in E^\perp$ we conclude that $x=0$. Hence, $E^\perp=\{0\}$ and our claim is justified. Meaning, that $H=E$. In other words,
$$H=\overline{\text{span}\{e_{ik}:\, i\in \mathbb{N},\ 1\leq k \leq N_1\}}$$
and every $e_{ik}$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to the non zero eigenvalue $\lambda_i$.